# Record the mode before pressing <c-\><c-n> in terminal

Tags: terminal, normal-mode

I want to restore the pos of cursor in terminal when I reopen the terminal:

- If the mode was terminal mode before, it is easy to feed a 'a' to terminal to change from normal mode to terminal mode.
- If the mode was normal mode before, record the pos of cursor and recover it after reopening the terminal

Now I get stuck in obtaining the mode when I press `<c-\><c-n>` and then to call restore or other functions. Cause after pressing `<c-\><c-n>`, the mode (output of `mode()`) will always be normal.

Is there some feasible methods?

Answer (score 1):

patch 8.2.1978 provide special key `<cmd>` to avoid mode changes.